# Script to automaticly draw borders around text layers in gimp

Tags: gimp

I am drawing maps in gimp. I have to make text labels with borders around it which are connected with lines, to dots on map.

How hard is it (I never tried scripting in gimp) to write a macro/script which will create/recreate a separate layer and draw lines and borders on it?

I want to speed up my work but I'm afraid that writing a programm will take too much time, coz I'm new to it.

Comment: Yes of course. By the way, I've found that I can use paths to draw lines and borders much faster than I ever did before))

Comment: Yes. And in 2.10 there is even the API that matches the "line" mode of the "Edit>Stroke path" so you get really clean lines.